# Chrome auto downloads something called 'frame' every time I click a link on YouTube?

Tags: google-chrome

This is what it looks like:

[image]

I've looked through the browser settings to see if there's an option to disable auto downloads, but there seems to be no such option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what's happening is that Youtube is trying to start up their "[Google Frame](http://www.google.com/chromeframe)" plug-in for HTML5 enhancements.

It also seems to have something to do with YouTube linking to your Google+ account.

Log out of (all) Google services, [clear your browser's cache](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95582?hl=en), and log back into your Google account..

More info from Google Groups:

- [Everytime I go on YouTube, Chrome downloads a file called "frame", how do I stop it?](http://productforums.google.com/d/msg/youtube/h5jc8D56Vas/I55DGumEYywJ)
- [youtube keeps downloading frame](http://productforums.google.com/d/msg/youtube/VmYphWk6TTk/spORulFZCJ4J)

Comment: Signing out, and then re-signing in resolved the issue. Thank you for your help.